# How to center JQM grid?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-grid

So is it possible to center grid in jQuery mobile. For example i have this http://jsfiddle.net/nonamez/Pr8pa/

```
<div class="ui-grid-d">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:60px">A</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:60px">B</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:60px">C</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-d"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:60px">C</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:60px">A</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:60px">B</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:60px">C</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:60px">A</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:60px">B</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:60px">C</div></div>
</div>
```

And it looks like [image]

Comment: @Gajotres, how many more tags will you be creating today?  ;)  You've flooded out the new tag list in the 10k tools!

Comment: I am trying to make jQuery Mobile group a little bit readable. But I think I will slow it down. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/BFfWc/

Change:

```
<div class="ui-grid-d">
```

To:

```
<div class="ui-grid-c">
```

### HTML :

```
<div class="ui-grid-c">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><div style="height:60px" class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">A</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><div style="height:60px" class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">B</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><div style="height:60px" class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">C</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-d"><div style="height:60px" class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">C</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-a"><div style="height:60px" class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">A</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><div style="height:60px" class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">B</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><div style="height:60px" class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">C</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-a"><div style="height:60px" class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">A</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><div style="height:60px" class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">B</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><div style="height:60px" class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">C</div></div>
</div>
```